# Kubernetes CronJob

Tags: cron, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to run the [Cron Job example](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/) provided on the Kubernetes web site. It says the prerequisites are Kubernetes cluster version >=1.5 (I am currently on 1.6.6) and batch/v2alpha1 API turned on.

The document mentioned that we need to pass "--runtime-config=batch/v2alpha1=true" argument while **bringing up the API server** to turn on the batch/v2alpha1 API, but it does not mention how exactly to do that. The link given for [Turn on or off an API version for your cluster](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/cluster-management/#turn-on-or-off-an-api-version-for-your-cluster) does not mention detailed procedures neither.

I am quite confused on where should I pass the "--runtime-config=batch/v2alpha1=true" argument, and how exactly should I do that.
I saw in some places mentioned that we could download kube-apiserver file, but I tired to run it without success, and I was quite confused about what kind of argument should I pass.

As mentioned above I am using a 1.6.6 kubernetes cluster, and I am running it on Google Cloud Platform.

Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Duplicate with a more comprehensive answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45580361/kubernetes-cronjob-needs-to-set-a-runtime-config-of-batch-v2alpha1-true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For GCP, the api version you're looking for is only enabled by default starting in 1.8.  You'll find a note to that effect here:

- https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG-1.8.md

You could spin up an [alpha cluster](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/alpha-clusters) if you wanted to stick with an earlier major version of the api but with the beta api available. Those alpha clusters are deleted after 30 days, so it may not be what you want.

Instead, if you want to upgrade to 1.8, try these steps:

View the available versions:

```
$ gcloud container get-server-config --zone=<YOUR ZONE>
```

Get your cluster name:

```
$ gcloud container clusters list
```

Then upgrade your cluster:

```
$ gcloud container clusters upgrade <CLUSTER_NAME> --master --cluster-version=<CLUSTER_VERSION>
$ gcloud container clusters upgrade <CLUSTER_NAME> --cluster-version=<CLUSTER_VERSION>
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

on the master server api configuration stored in this location /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml.

1. take the backup of this file.
2. add the new argument in  **command:** section.
3. restart the node, it will start with new argument.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have 3 nodes now, and I have logged in to all of them but I did not see the kube-apiserver.yaml file in the above mentioned location.

Comment: this will be only in the master node. Are you able to see api process running on the master node? if its running look at the parent process its pointing too.

Comment: okay, I got it wrong, it was not any of the 3 nodes in my cluster. I can see the IP address of the Entry Point of my cluster, is it the master node? how should I ssh into it? using which user name and credential file?

Comment: yeah, that is the server you need to change. sorry I didn't have environment in gcp.