# Kubernetes cronjob needs to set a runtime config of batch/v2alpha1=true

Tags: kubernetes

When I want to run the demo, I get the error:

> error: error validating "cronJob_example.yaml": error validating data:
>   couldn't find type: v2alpha1.CronJob; if you choose to ignore these
>   errors, turn validation off with --validate=false

Then I found:

> Prerequisites You need a working Kubernetes cluster at version >= 1.4
>   (for ScheduledJob), >= 1.5 (for CronJob), with batch/v2alpha1 API
>   turned on by passing --runtime-config=batch/v2alpha1=true while
>   bringing up the API server (see Turn on or off an API version for your
>   cluster for more).

The above conditions need to do `--runtime-config=batch/v2alpha1=true`, but I don't know where and how to execute it

Answer (score 4):

Here is it documented. https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/ we need to enable this feature in API server.

on the master server you need to add the line command section in this file `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml`. then restart whole cluster.

After restart check the api version. we should see the feature enabled.

```
kubectl api-versions |grep batch
batch/v1
batch/v2alpha1
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this! When I checked the direct link is slightly different at https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/automated-tasks-with-cron-jobs.  Also if you are using OpenShift it requires "CronJob" not "ScheduledJob" in the yaml file.